# IdentityServer4 - Refresh Tokens Hybrid Flow - Cookies and storage

Tags: .net, security, identityserver4, access-token, refresh-token

I've followed Quickstart Hybrid Flow [here](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/quickstarts/5_hybrid_and_api_access.html) but I need some help and advices about saving tokens after using refresh token.

If I say true, the option *SaveTokens* allows to save tokens in cookies.

Firstly, is it a good idea to store access and refresh tokens in a cookie (concerns about security) ?

Other question, I retrieve correctly refresh token via the code
`var refreshToken = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("refresh_token");` but now, when I get the new access token, how can I store it (no `SetTokenAsync` method) ?... because without that, I retrieve the old acces token when I call `var refreshToken = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token");` whereas I would like get the new.

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at the information from my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54498454/still-logged-in-mvc-site-but-cant-call-web-api/54507122#54507122).

Comment: Thanks, it helps me for saving tokens (access & refresh) after using refresh token. Have you an opinion about saving them in cookies (secure or not)... is it useful to use PKCE in this flow ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/grant_types.html):

> Interactive clients should use an authorization code-based flow. To
>   protect against code substitution, either hybrid flow or PKCE should
>   be used.

Thus the combination of PKCE and hybrid flow is not necessary and probably not useful.

> If PKCE is available, this is the simpler solution to the problem.
>
> PKCE is already the official recommendation for native applications
>   and SPAs - and with the release of ASP.NET Core 3 also by default
>   supported in the OpenID Connect handler as well.

So instead of using the hybrid flow, configure it as [interactive ASP.NET Core MVC client](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/master/samples/Quickstarts/2_InteractiveAspNetCore/src/IdentityServer/Config.cs#L40).

```
new Client
{
    ClientId = "mvc",
    ClientSecrets = { new Secret("secret".Sha256()) },

    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Code,
    RequireConsent = false,
    RequirePkce = true,

    // where to redirect to after login
    RedirectUris = { "http://localhost:5002/signin-oidc" },

    // where to redirect to after logout
    PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "http://localhost:5002/signout-callback-oidc" },

    AllowedScopes = new List<string>
    {
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile
    }
}
```

Where the mvc client has the expected configuration:

```
.AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
{
    options.Authority = "http://localhost:5000";
    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

    options.ClientId = "mvc";
    options.ClientSecret = "secret";
    options.ResponseType = "code";

    options.SaveTokens = true;
});
```

I can also recommend [this post](https://brockallen.com/2019/01/03/the-state-of-the-implicit-flow-in-oauth2/) from Brock Allen. This may answer your question about cookies. You can also check [the post](https://leastprivilege.com/2019/01/18/an-alternative-way-to-secure-spas-with-asp-net-core-openid-connect-oauth-2-0-and-proxykit/) of Dominick Baier.

For information on how to use the refresh token please read [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54498454/still-logged-in-mvc-site-but-cant-call-web-api/54507122#54507122).